# How to assign the value of toggle button (ngx-toggle) in angular page according to the output of a bash script?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an Angular page, where I have a few toggle buttons. The state of those, I have to determine based on the output of a bash script. I'm using ngx-toggle. Now, these toggle button shows if JMS adapters are running on different servers. And I have to take that status from the server.

```
<ngx-toggle id="devBase" [value]=""></ngx-toggle>
```

Till now, I've tried to read the status from a text file, but I'm unable to update the value of toggle buttons.

```
readTextFile(file) {
let rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
rawFile.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (rawFile.readyState === 4) {
    if (rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0) {
      let allText = rawFile.responseText;
      let lines = allText.split("\n");
      let devBase: boolean;
      for (let line = 0; line < lines.length; line++) {
        if (lines[line].trim() == "devBase=1") {
          console.log(devBase);
          devBase = true;
        }
        if (lines[line].trim() == "devBase=0") {
          console.log(devBase);
          devBase = false;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
rawFile.send(null);
```

}

When I'm using [(value)]="devBase", it is unable to process.

Comment: It' unclear what you're asking, and why would you use AJAX when you have Angular to do it for you ? Either use Angular, or remove your tag. I'm also removing your bash tag, since it has nothing to do with a bash script.

Comment: @trichetriche Thanks for your edit. I've never really mentioned AJAX. I wanted to update the status of toggle button from the parameters, like devBase. it is working now. I'll add an answer to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two way binding is working. So the html code will be 
`<ngx-toggle id="devBase" [(value)]="devBase"></ngx-toggle>`

The reason it was not working earlier is that the devBase was defined inside a function in my ts file. I returned this value from the function and take it in a universal variable.

```
readTextFile(file) {
let rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
let lines;
rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
rawFile.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (rawFile.readyState === 4) {
    if (rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0) {
      let allText = rawFile.responseText;
      lines = allText.split("\n");
      }
  }
}
rawFile.send(null);
return lines;
```

}

And in the outside of this function,

```
lines: string[];
this.lines = this.readTextFile("http://orapoc06:8087/JavaBridgeTemplate621/dist/assets/files/status.txt");
```